# Set Braces in XYPic, XYMatrix

Tags: matrices, xy-pic

I want to add three braces to a xymatrix in a xypic environment. Here's how I got so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}

\xy
\xymatrix@C=10pt@R=20pt{
&\\
 & A_1\POS*\frm{^\}},+U*++!D\txt{A to B} & B_2 & C_3 \POS*\frm{^\}},+U*++!D\txt{C to D} & D_4\\
 & E_5 & F_6 \POS*\frm{_\}},+U*++!D\txt{F to G} & G_7 & H_8
}
\endxy

\end{document}
```

[image: current output]

Now there are two issues:

1. I want the braces to span from A to B, C to D and the one at the bottom from F to G. At the moment, they only embrace a single element. How can I do this using the xymatrix [rr] syntax?
2. I want to add the label for the bottom brace from below. At the moment, it is still displayed on top.

I appreciate any comments on this issue!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Please give a completely compilable example. A screenshot would also be helpful, but as you don't have enough reputation, somebody else can do that then.

Comment: @canaaerus: I added the package definitions required to compile. I would appreciate if anyone could make a screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

If using another package is an option, I would suggest you to use `PGF/TikZ`, perhaps in combination with [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) (based on `TikZ` and specialized to commutative diagrams); here's a little example using a `matrix of math nodes` and the `brace` decoration from the `decorations.pathreplacing` library:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, name=m,inner xsep=0pt] 
{
A_1 & B_2 & C_3 & D_4 \\
E_5 & F_6 & G_7 & H_8 \\
};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace}]
  (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-2.north east) node[midway,auto] {$A$ to $B$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace}]
  (m-1-3.north west) -- (m-1-4.north east) node[midway,auto] {$C$ to $D$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
  (m-2-2.south west) -- (m-2-3.south east) node[midway,auto,swap] {$F$ to $G$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Tikz is what I'm usually using for these kinds of tasks, but I need to alter a present \xypic figure from a paper. Nevertheless, this is a pretty good example.

Answer (score 3):

**Ross Moore** kindly responded to my problem in the \xypic mailing list. Here's his solution:

You can add those decorations afterwards, using the implicit
names of the matrix cells. 
e.g.

```
\xy
\xymatrix "M"@C=10pt@R=20pt{
&\\
 & A_1 & B_2 & C_3 & D_4\\
 & E_5 & F_6 & G_7 & H_8
}%
 \POS"M2,2"."M2,3"!C*\frm{^\}},+U*++!D\txt{A to B} 
 ,"M2,4"."M2,5"!C*\frm{^\}},+U*++!D\txt{C to D} 
 ,"M3,3"."M3,4"!C*\frm{_\}},+D*++!U\txt{F to G} 
\endxy
```

[image: output of above code]

With this, you probably do not need the row-spacing to be as large
as you made it ( @R=20pt ).

In the above coding below I added a name "M" for the matrix. 
This isn't necessary here, but would be if you wanted to draw 
connections between the cells of 2 or more matrices, so it is 
a useful technique to know about.